# Trying to nest a dictionary from a previous dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

so I have the following scenario:

```
dictionary=[
{category1:clothes, category2:cheap, category3:10},
{category1:clothes, category2:normal, category3:20}]
```

I need a dictionary that goes `{clothes:{cheap:10, normal:20}}`
All I have figured out is something that prints them individually

```
for i in range(len(dictionary)):
print({dictionary[i]['category1']:{dictionary[i][category2],dictionary[i][category3]}}
```

But it prints them individually, and I can't figure out how to nest them together since this just gives me two dictionaries with the format I want, but the nested dictionary just has either the values from the first list or the second. I have also tried

```
[{item['category1']: {'Attribute': attr_key, 'Value': item[attr_key]}}
    for item in dictionary for attr_key in item if attr_key != 'category1']
```

It is the same, it gives more lines whereas I just need one dictionary with cat1 and the other ones nested in its dictionary.

Comment: can you please rephrase this question with a brief and to the point explanation. thanks

Comment: suppose if there is an another dict in `dictionary` such as `{category1:clothes, category2:normal, category3:20}` how it would be fit in your case, I am not clear about your example

Answer (score 1):

```
raw = {}
for item in dictionary:
    value1 = item.get('category2')
    value2 = item.get('category3')
    raw.update({value1:value2})

data = {}
data[dictionary[0].get('category1')] = raw
```

**Output:**

```
{'clothes': {'cheap': 10, 'normal': 20}}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is close, but I need the items in the value field to be a single dictionary, not a list of dictionaries. Unleash your Bankai for the first time for me here! :D

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
import collections

dictionary=[
    {'category1':'clothes', 'category2':'cheap', 'category3':10},
    {'category1':'clothes', 'category2':'normal', 'category3':20}
]

newdict = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for item in dictionary:
  newdict[item['category1']].update({item['category2']: item['category3']})
print(newdict)
```